# issue trigger happen once but then die on subject (rxjs)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i have issue with a Subject that when i trigger it once it work just nice but when i change
it like it die somewhere

as well i try active some kind of timer that as well never happened.

the code is it on my [gitHub](https://github.com/Sivanwol/PlaygroundWithAkita/blob/master/src/app/SiteTests/components/customers)

1. this is the service that i use at i call the method requestNewStock

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  tap,
  switchMap,
  timeInterval,
  mergeMap,
  find,
  delay,
  bufferCount,
  distinctUntilChanged,
  timeout,
  publish,
  exhaustMap,
  take,
  concatMap,
  repeat,
  catchError
} from "rxjs/operators";
import { Stock } from "../models/stock.model";
import { StockStore } from "../store/stock.store";
import {
  Subject,
  BehaviorSubject,
  of,
  Observable,
  from,
  interval,
  forkJoin,
  ConnectableObservable,
  race
} from "rxjs";
import { StockQuery } from "../queries/stock.query";
import { RequestPollService } from "./request-poll.service";
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class StockService {
  private refreshRate: number;
  private updateStateArr: Set<string>;
  private stocks: string[] = [];
  private notifyStockFetching$: Subject<null> = new Subject<null>();
  constructor(
    private stockStore: StockStore,
    private stockQuery: StockQuery,
    private requestPollService: RequestPollService
  ) {}
  handleStocks(): Observable<void> {
    return this.notifyStockFetching$.pipe(
      find(() => this.stocks.length > 0),
      mergeMap(stocks => this.handleStockFetchingData()),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return of([])
      }),
      delay(this.refreshRate),
      repeat()
    );
  }

  getStocks(): Observable<Array<Stock>> {
    return this.stockQuery.items$;
  }

  public updateRefreashRate(refreshRate: number) {
    this.refreshRate = refreshRate;
    this.notifyStockFetching$.next();
  }

  public requestNewStock(stocks: string[]) {
    this.stocks = stocks;
    this.updateStateArr = new Set();
    this.stockStore.clearStocks();
    this.notifyStockFetching$.next();
  }

  private handleStockFetchingData(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.stocks).pipe(
      mergeMap(stock => {
        return this.requestPollService.requestStock(stock).pipe(
          tap(res => {
            if (res) {
              const updateState = this.updateStateArr.has(res.stockCode);
              if (!updateState) {
                this.updateStateArr.add(res.stockCode);
                this.stockStore.addNewStockItem(res); // we update the stock as this stock we just got
              } else {
                this.stockStore.updateStock(res.stockCode, res);
              }
            }
          })
        );
      }, 3),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return of([])
      })
    );
  }
}
```

2. from the compount stock-list.component.ts in the init i use this

```js
import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Stock } from "../../models/stock.model";
import { SelectItem } from "primeng/api";
import { StockService } from "../../services/stock.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-stock-list",
  templateUrl: "./stock-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./stock-list.component.scss"]
})
export class StockListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subject: Subject<null> = new Subject();
  values: Stock[] = [];
  origValues: Stock[] = [];
  selectedItem: Stock;
  sortOptions: SelectItem[];
  sortKey: string;
  sortField: string;
  sortOrder: number;
  displayDialog: boolean;
  constructor(
    private stockService: StockService,
    private changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subject.next();
    this.subject.complete();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // this.mockData();
    this.stockService.handleStocks().subscribe(
      () => {},
      error => console.error(error)
    );
    this.stockService.getStocks().subscribe(
      stocks => {
        this.values = stocks;
        this.origValues = stocks;
      },
      error => console.error(error)
    );
    this.sortOptions = [
      { label: "Desc high Rate", value: "!high" },
      { label: "Asc high Rate", value: "high" },
      { label: "Desc low Rate", value: "!low" },
      { label: "Asc low Rate", value: "low" },
      { label: "Desc volume Rate", value: "!volume" },
      { label: "Asc volume Rate", value: "volume" }
    ];
  }

  onDialogHide() {
    this.selectedItem = null;
  }
  mockData() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
      const randSeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      const randSeedChange = Number(
        (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1).toFixed(2)
      );
      const objSeed: Stock = {
        change: randSeedChange,
        changePresent: `${randSeedChange}%`,
        high: Number((randSeed * 2.4).toFixed(2)),
        low: Number((randSeed * 1.4).toFixed(2)),
        open: Number((randSeed * 1.8).toFixed(2)),
        stockCode: "APP",
        volume: randSeed * 8,
        lastUpdate: "12.2.2020"
      };
      this.values = [...this.values, objSeed];
    }
    this.origValues = [...this.values];
  }
  onSearch($event) {
    const arr = [];
    const value = $event.target.value;
    if (value === "") {
      this.values = this.origValues.slice();
    } else {
      this.values = this.origValues.filter(item =>
        item.volume.toString().includes(value)
      );
    }
    this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
  }
  moreInfo($event, item: Stock) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
    this.displayDialog = true;
    $event.preventDefault();
  }
  goDeepInfo($event) {}
  removeItem($event, item: Stock) {}
  onSortChange($event) {
    const value = $event.value;

    if (value.indexOf("!") === 0) {
      this.sortOrder = -1;
      this.sortField = value.substring(1, value.length);
    } else {
      this.sortOrder = 1;
      this.sortField = value;
    }
  }
}
```

as i said in the end the subscribed happened but i got first time data and then it die i need help i don't understand as to why.

ok i update a bit the code still issue persist what happened that it work correctly once i do see data been fetch and shown i do see timer happens (means it is loop) but it seems like nothing happened after at
i did look into at i think it relevant something around here
just no idea what or why btw no error what so ever and remove for not the takeutill just for safe side.

this what i saw happend once then it not getting any where look like the

```js
private handleStockFetchingData(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.stocks).pipe(
      mergeMap(stock => {
        return this.requestPollService.requestStock(stock).pipe(
          tap(res => {
            if (res) {
              const updateState = this.updateStateArr.has(res.stockCode);
              if (!updateState) {
                this.updateStateArr.add(res.stockCode);
                this.stockStore.addNewStockItem(res); // we update the stock as this stock we just got
              } else {
                this.stockStore.updateStock(res.stockCode, res);
              }
            }
          })
        );
      }, 3),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return of([])
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: when do you .next on this.subject?

Comment: Two plaaces when use requestNewStock and updateRefreashRate

Comment: why do you need this takeUntil ? Just remove it and it should work as expected.

Comment: performance when u route out the what ever page  i want make sure it dead as well prevent memory leak why u think this the issue if so what it prevent only the second when the subject (poor name sorry) get next on the destroy on the comp and no do nothing

Comment: you are missing the constructor brackets on   subject: Subject<null> = new Subject;
and I would add catcherror in both pipes of the subscriptions in your component to see if the subject breaks. There are 2 reasons for a subject to stop producing, either it completes or it throws an error. Have a look at the example here with takeUntil => https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

Comment: ok i triple check this it not connected to takeUntil what happened it look like the data fetching once means it pass the work flow and the next  time when happened next it just not going anywhere

Comment: but @IvanMihaylov this issue this happened even when i did remove takeUntil

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This funny the find was the issue this what prevent it one of th pitfall of rx no logs no a thing lucky i just start remove and refactor few areas.
thanks to all

Comment: It helps if you post your solution in order to help others.